# Query for how many downvotes a user has received so far

Tags: support, votes, data-explorer, down-votes

I was trying to find the ratio of "how many downvotes I have cast (on others' posts obviously)" : "how many downvotes my posts has received".

The question basically boils down to finding "how many downvotes my posts has received?" because finding out "how many downvotes I have cast" is trivial and the info is publicly visible to everyone on my profile.

So, I need a query for "The number of downvotes a particular user's posts has received so far".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a query present to find the [User Ratio of Upvotes to Downvotes Received](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/6006/user-ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received).

```
select
    SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Up Votes],
    SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Down Votes],
    (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS float) / CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS float)) AS [Up Votes to Down Votes]
from
    Votes v inner join Posts p on v.PostId=p.Id
where
    p.OwnerUserId=##UserId##
```

There is another query present [to find the number of up vote and down vote ratio for all users.](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/6014/ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for.. so are these queries uptodate?

Comment: Keshav Srinivasan tops the chart! :D

Comment: @Rickross SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday 03:00 UTC. The first entry in the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) has the relative duration since the last update (also shown on the front page).

Comment: @rene Thanks ... sometimes I hv seen those data not to match with the current stats.. tht's why asked.

Comment: @Rickross yeah, it is a fair question. If you need uptodate data a better option is using the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) but that requires scripting in some programming language and is limited in its capabilities, specially if you want a data aggregation over lots of rows. For your specific use case described here I think SEDE with at max 7 days old data is fine.

Comment: I am unable to generate mine though. What is UserID? "Macindows" does not seem to be working.

Comment: @Macindows If you will go to your profile, you will see this url in browser: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4893/macindows Here `4893` is your userId.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Got it finally lol. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @Macindows You are welcome. Glad to know it helped :)